# What is a "recovery set" in Intel MSM?

Tags: raid

Intel Matrix Storage Manager offers several levels of RAID.  Most of these I am familiar with (RAID 0 striping, RAID 1 mirror, RAID 1+0 striped mirror, RAID 5 striping with redundancy).  But there's also a "Recovery Set".  What is this and how does it differ from RAID 1 mirroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a recovery-backup solution, [see this PDF for documentation.](http://mbforum.gigabyte.de/forumdownload//Software/OEM_Technical%20Guide%20RST_rev1_0%2010%200%20Release.pdf)

Its part of the [Intel Rapid Recovery Technology](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-026142.htm)

.
[image]

.
[image]

.
[image]

Comment: Ahh, so it's a mirror to an external drive that's not always available.  That explains everything perfectly (except for why the feature is included on server motherboards).

Comment: It seems that choosing RAID 1 instead of "Recovery" may cause inconvenience when a disk is failed...
https://communities.intel.com/message/133614#133614